# Plotting two lines for different years in one graph using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time

I am trying to plot the data for two different years of temperature, but I can't seem to get it rihgt. I want to have two seperate lines for each year so that I can compare them directly to each other. It is important for me to keep the proper dates and not convert to something such as days from start.

[image: first few rows of data]

[image: graph]
[image: code]

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: `aes(..., group=Year)`?